# Draw circle in qlabel (show image stream camera)

Tags: qt, opencv

My project is stream camera in qt and find circle in stream, draw red it. At present, i resolved stream camera in qt but i don't have idea to draw red it. It will same [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5l_3T-ThlA&t=87s). They find vehicle and draw it. Can anybody contribute idea for me to complete project?

Stream camera, Using: qcamera.
I don't have keyword to search it and newbie qt.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you started yet? Or do you want ideas on how to get started?

To draw a circle around the QLabel, you can change the label's style sheet.

Comment: Qt's style sheets use CSS. [A quick google search will offer you a method to make circles in CSS, as well as other shapes](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/). You can look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) for info on style sheets in Qt. You should be able to find a style sheet option in the Property Editor (It has "Property" and "Value" written on it). Update the style sheet ot make a circle around your QLabels. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @MadManiac I searched draw circle in Qlabel but At present, my issue is not determine Draw on stream camera with 30 - 60 fps.

Comment: It will you see car and truck work on road and In screen if Verifying car or truck it will draw rectangle and number after propram will count up.